# Email not send within suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

For some reasons I can't seem to receive an email from my suitescript.

Here's my code.

```
 define(["N/email"], function(email) {

    function afterSubmit(scriptContext) {

        var newOrder = scriptContext.newRecord.id;

        email.send({
                author: 17874,
                recipients: "sam172@gmail.com",
                subject: "mail from netsuite",
                body: "test body email order id: " + newOrder
        });
       }

    return {
        afterSubmit: afterSubmit
    };

});
```

This email will send when a sales order is created.
My order is send through Webservice API and every time an order is send to Netsuite, it will trigger this script to send me an email when the sales order get created.

I've been testing by place multiple order, but never receive any email.  There's no error on the netsuite server error log.

What could be the problem here?  thanks

Comment: Are you in Sandbox? Remember Sandbox emails can only be sent to the user testing the script.

Comment: Yes I'm in Sandbox.  I didn't know that.  Thanks @AdolfoGarza

Comment: Email is working now, I just set to myself which I'm the one who testing the script on Sandbox.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are in a Sandbox Account, Sandbox emails can only be sent to the user testing the script.